# Reinforcement learning actions and decisions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

What RL does actually update in order to reach always a desired output? Is it true that the inputs (or the Agent actions) have to be re-updated whenever an RL reaches a bad output (or decision) based on a reward system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question as: *"if my RL model makes a bad decision, does that mean that the model would adjust my inputs?"*

No, you don't update the inputs, you update **parameters** in your model. With a proper learning rate, your new parameters (hopefully) will be a better fit for your model.

Comment: So that means what ever comes from the sensory input is totally independent from the RL agent, but, the RL will guarantee to update its parameters according to any input on a condition that desired output will be reached. Right?

Comment: @Leb_Broth Your inputs are independent to your model parameters. They are different things. As long as your implement is correct, your RL model should be able to update your parameters based on the results (positive or negative).

Comment: so an RL is not an input/output system. It's just a trained environment that can suggest decisions based on an internal structure composed of millions of parameters (acquired from previous training), am I getting the idea?

Comment: @Leb_Broth I think you make the whole thing too complicated. RL is a not an environment, it's a statistical model that you can use to adjust your model parameters. Assuming your adjustments are good, your RL model should be able to do a good job given your inputs. A good example is chess.

Comment: @Leb_Broth Think of it like "my RL will be good enough for me to use. I give it some inputs, and it will make some good decisions".

Comment: ok i get now. Even if i gave it a bad input, it will give me a good result. Like showing fire to a baby, a good reinforcement learned baby would take the decision to steer away from danger.

Comment: so basically an RL is the deep-learning version of the old model predictive control (MPC used in drones stability by steering the motors always to optimal and desired conditions. Btw, MPC is also a Chess gaming concept.

Comment: @Leb_Broth No... That's not right. If you have further questions on how RL is related to machine learning, and what machine learning is really is. You can start a new question.

Comment: you can google "reinforcement learning versus model predictive control" and there are tens of papers about the subject.

Comment: @Leb_Broth I am not an expert in MPC. I'd suggest you to start a new question, so we can talk about it with other forum users who might have better knowledge than me.